# PHP MySQL check combinations and show certain value

Tags: php, mysql

I want to develop an admission system where candidate will choose their subject combinations and based on the combination, I want to show the fee amount in a textbox.

My `subject` & `fee_structure` table structure is .....

[image: Table Structure]

The `fee_structure` table has 296 combinations/rows.

Now students has to choose their subjects from the below form.

[image: subjects]

Based on their subject choice, I want to show the `fee_amt` in a textbox.

For your information subject choices are from `subject` table and based on the `Honours`(subject), `General 1`(pass_1), `General 2`(pass_2), I want to show the `fee_amt`.

> Like : If `subject` is BENGALI, `pass_1` is EDUCATION and `pass_2` is PHYSICAL EDUCATION, then the `fee_amt` will be `5520.00`.

I don't know how and where to start.

Please help me on this.

**UPDATE :**

> `subject` or  `pass_1` or  `pass_2` can be any one of the subjects BENGALI, EDUCATION and PHYSICAL EDUCATION and the `fee_amt` will be `5520.00`.

Comment: Simple: use this `SELECT fee_amt FROM fee where subject = 'BENGALI' AND pass_1 = 'EDUCATION ' AND pass_2 = 'PHYSICAL EDUCATION'`. through ajax.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Thanks for your answer. But It can be other things also. Please see my update

Comment: @FrayneKonok Please see the update

Comment: _can be any one of the_ means?

Comment: @FrayneKonok can be anyone means subject can be any one of the three subjects BENGALI, EDUCATION and PHYSICAL EDUCATION, pass_1 can be any one of the subjects BENGALI, EDUCATION and PHYSICAL EDUCATION, or pass_2 can be any one of the subjects BENGALI, EDUCATION and PHYSICAL EDUCATION

Comment: this is not a standard.... You have to change this concept

Comment: @FrayneKonok this is not my standard exactly. It is a requirement of a client.

Comment: Than you have to use `find_in_set` or `IN`. This may work on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112243/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-raj).

Answer (score 0):

After a long [Conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112243/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-raj) with OP, It is final / clear that user can't select the same options from different select box. So the query may be looks like:

```
SELECT fee_amt FROM fee where subject IN ('BENGALI', 'EDUCATION', 'PHYSICAL EDUCATION') AND pass_1 IN ('BENGALI', 'EDUCATION', 'PHYSICAL EDUCATION') AND pass_2 IN ('BENGALI', 'EDUCATION', 'PHYSICAL EDUCATION');
```

Where `'BENGALI', 'EDUCATION', 'PHYSICAL EDUCATION'` comes from the user selected options and the total things done through ajax.